# python subprocess never stops when called with -i argument

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script that calls another python script (script2).  I want to get the print statements from script2 during the process, not only at the end.  I have this code:

```
command = ['python', '-i', script2]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, 
                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
                       stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

print "process started"

while process.poll() is None:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print line
```

This code does indeed print the output to the screen, but the subprocess never ends.
However, changing `command` to `command = ['python', script2]` ends the subprocess, but only prints the output to the screen AFTER the subprocess ended.

How can I get the desired behaviour?  Thanks on beforehand,
Roel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking your subprocess with `-u` (and do not use `-i`). This will stop its output from being buffered. You don't see any output until it ends because it writes all its output into a buffer, which isn't flushed until it either fills up or the process finishes.

Comment: Excellent, this works as I want it.  It's not the first time I struggle with command line arguments.  I don't find an overview of the different options and their meaning.  Where could I find that?

Comment: Try `python --help` or see here: http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html (Python 2.7) http://docs.python.org/py3k/using/cmdline.html (Python 3.2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to avoid the trap, but from the help text of the interpreter:

> -i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
>            if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x

The import thing is that it *forces a prompt*. That means after executing the script you have an interpreter prompt again and access to all variables and stuff. The interpreter waits for input and doesn't terminate until it receives a keyboard interrupt, `exit()` is given as prompt input or the process is simply killed.